# Is $\dim U=\dim V-1$ if U is maximal with respect to inclusion?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does a subspace U of $V$ that is maximal with respect to inclusion have dimension $\dim U=\dim V-1$?

Comment: what's the definition you're using for *maximal with respect to inclusion*?

Comment: there is no subspace W⊂V for which U⊂W (proper inclusion)

Comment: Is the inclusion $W\subset V$ supposed to be proper too?

Comment: yes, both are proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_0 \in V$ with $v_0 \notin U$. Then, by maximality of $U$, $$V = \operatorname{span}(U \cup\{v_0\}) = U+\langle v_0 \rangle,$$ where $\langle v_0 \rangle$ is the subspace spanned by $v_0$. In fact, $V = U \oplus \langle v_0 \rangle$ (why?) and then $\dim V = \dim U + 1$.